# What's the best way to move a UIBezierPath stroke in Swift 4?

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, core-graphics, swift4

I am trying to implement a cursor that can change position in Swift 4 using UIBezierPath stroke. Currently, I have a function that has a parameter location which contains the new x and y position of the 'cursor'. I'd like to use this location parameter as the new position of the cursor in the UIView. My currently implementation renders another cursor each time the function is called. Is there a way to change the position of one instance of a UIBezierPath? See example code below for reference.

```
private var cursor:UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath()

public func changeCursorLocation(location: ScreenCoordinates) {
    self.cursor = UIBezierPath()

    UIColor.black.setStroke()
    self.cursor.lineWidth = 2

    self.cursor.move(to: CGPoint(x: location.x, y: location.y))
    self.cursor.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: location.x + 100, y: location.y)) // change if staff space changes
    self.cursor.stroke()
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Draw the cursor as `CAShapeLayer` object. This lets you move the cursor without having to redraw it.

```
class MyView: UIView {
    let cursor = CAShapeLayer()

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setup()
    }

    func setup() {
        // Draw cursor and add it to this view's layer
        let path = UIBezierPath()
        path.move(to: .zero)
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 100, y: 0))

        cursor.path = path.cgPath
        cursor.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        cursor.lineWidth = 2

        layer.addSublayer(cursor)

        changeCursorLocation(location: CGPoint(x: 50, y: 100))
    }

    func changeCursorLocation(location: CGPoint) {
        cursor.position = location
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hello, I just tried implementing this but whenever I change the position of the CAShapeLayer the cursor disappears. I forgot to mention that this is implemented inside a class that extends UIView. I am calling the setup() function inside the draw() function of the UIView.

Comment: setup() should be called once only - to draw the cursor shape. From then on you only need to change the cursor's location. You don't need the draw() function and you definitely shouldn't call setup() inside it. When do you need to change the cursor location?

Comment: I am calling the setup() only once, I also tried it inside the init function but the shape still disappears after calling the changeCursorLocation(). The cursor changes location every time a button is clicked which changes its position

Comment: required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        
        let loc = ScreenCoordinates(x: 100, y: 100)
        setupCursor(location: loc)
        changeCursorLocation(location: CGPoint(x: 120, y: 100))
    }

Comment: init() is the correct place to put setup(). The draw() method is for custom drawing code only. Once you've added the path to the CAShapeLayer and added the CAShapeLayer to the view's layer, the cursor will show. Comment out the draw() method, because it's redrawing the view's layer, overwriting the cursor sublayer.

Comment: Thank you. It works now. So it is bad practice to override the draw() function of UIView? CAShapeLayer should always be used to render in UIView?

Comment: Using draw() is valid approach. Creating layers is just a different approach, which seems more object-oriented to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your Bezier path starting from 0,0 and then apply an x/y translation transform to the drawing context before drawing it. The details depend on how you're doing your drawing (is the code you posted being called from a view's `draw(rect:)` method?)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you must make a custom UIView and you need to make a Class for any Geometric object you want to transform on UIView like this

(this only for straight geometric object : line, polyline, rectangle)

```
class GeoObj {

var path = UIBezierPath()

var points = [PointF]()

func createPath(){
    
    //make your path here
    points.removeAll()
    
    points.append(PointF(0,0))
    points.append(PointF(0,100))
    
    path.move(to: points[0].cgPoint)
    path.addLine(to: points[1].cgPoint)
    
}

}
```

(your Geometric Point)

```
struct PointF {

var x:Float = 0

var y:Float = 0

init(_ x:Float = 0, _ y:Float = 0) {
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
}

//convert to Core Graphic Point
var cgPoint : CGPoint {
    return CGPoint(x: CGFloat(self.x), y: CGFloat(self.y))
}

}
```

In UIView, you must have some geometric bundles (private array) to store all geometric models as below. Everytime your custom view init, you inject the business data to it and render into Core Graphic objects. (At higher level you can update these bundles and callback outside when user touch on something...)

```
private var geoModels = [GeoObj]() //you can create more
```

When UIView init, you must have the function to render your bundle on graphic context (put it in override func draw())

When you receive a movement from UIViewController such as (dx,dy), you run the function to move your object

```
func moveObj(_ id : String,_ dx: Float,_ dy:Float){
    
    for (i,obj) in geoModels.enumerated() {

        if obj.id == id { //identify the obj you want to move
        
         geoModels[i].points = translatePoints(points,dx,dy)
        
         geoModels[i].path = remakePath(geoModels[i].points) //you can do this in your Geometric class (related to your business logic...)

        }
        
    }

    invalidate()

    //invoke function draw() of UIView to force the context clear all its contents 
    
    //and you re-render your geometric bundle here
    
  }

   private func translatePoints(_ points : [PointF],_ dx:Float,_ dy:Float)->[PointF]{
    
    var new_points = points
    
    for (i,_) in new_points.enumerated(){
        
        new_points[i].x += dx
        new_points[i].y += dy
        
    }
    
    return new_points
    
}

private func remakePath(_ points:[PointF])->UIBezierPath{
    
    //do your businees code to re-create Path
    
    let path = UIBezierPath()
    
    path.move(to: points[0])
    path.addLine(to: points[1]) // ....draw as your business logic
    
    return path
    
}


private func invalidate(){
    
    self.setNeedsDisplay()
    
}
```

Keep in mind that everytime your call self.setNeedsDisplay() from UIView the graphic context will clear its content

```
 override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    
    print("draw")
        
    super.draw(rect)
    
    guard let ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else {
        return
    }
    
    //re-render your bundle here

    render(ctx)
       
    
  }
```

Do not worry about the lagging, I applied this way to my real project, everything moving smoothly.